# How can I restrict an Ubuntu user from accessing my Web application files?

Tags: linux, security, apache, web-applications, ubuntu-11.04

How can I restrict a logged in ubuntu user from accessing or modyfying(delete,copy,rename) my web application files stored in :

> /var/www

**BUT**

Still allow the user to access the web application via the browser by typing in the URL

> http://localhost/webapp

Is this possible?

Right now root owns all files but user www-data has rwx.
I have 2 users setup on the server

> 1.Admin
>
> 2.WebAppUser

WebAppUser will login and access the web application via the browser.

What would be the proper way of setting Linux file permissions in this case?

> **OS : Ubuntu Natty 11.04**

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a confusion on your part here.

You will have a user that uses a browser to send requests to a web app.

This is unrelated to the users rights. The web application to function would have to have of course the necessary priviliges to access all the required files but this is irrelevant to the user trying to access a URL from a browser.

You can set the appropriate permissions to the files so that a logged in user can not **manually navigate** to the directories and start modifying the files needing protection but this is not related to the web application itself.

Comment: "You can set the appropriate permissions to the files so that a logged in user can not manually navigate to the directories and start modifying the files needing protection but this is not related to the web application itself."
Yes, that is what I want to do but how do I set the appropriate permissions?

Comment: What is your question exactly?What are the highest permissions you can set or what is the command that sets the permissions?

Comment: The command the sets the permissions so that Ubuntu user : **WebAppUser** will not have access to files in folder /var/www
Bear in mind that the user will login on the server the web application is running on and access the web application on the very same server via a web browser. Thanks

Comment: For Ubuntu it should be as easy as right click and set permissions on the folder.You don't say what group the `WebAppUser` belongs.Just don't give rights to that group. You need to read this https://help.ubuntu.com/11.04/ubuntu-help/nautilus-file-properties-permissions.html

Comment: That's awesome, i will test it out and if it works as expected will mark the question as answered. Thanks!